# Difference between Main Queue / Current Queue & Main Thread / Background Thread in this case?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, queue

I'm executing the following method :

**MotionHandler.m**

```
-(void)startAccelerationUpdates
{
    [motionManagerstartDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error){.....}
}
```

on a background thread, as follows:

```
[currentMotionHandler performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startAccelerationUpdates) withObject:nil];
```

But the above method uses the `main Queue` (which is on the main thread) to perform the necessary updates even though I'm calling it on a background thread.. So are acceleration updates being performed on a background thread or on the main thread, I'm confused..?

What's even more interesting is that when I call the above method on background thread again, but this time using the `current Queue`, I get no updates. Could someone please explain the difference between running something on :

```
 1. a background thread but on the main queue

 2. a background thread but on the current queue 

 3. the main thread but on the main queue  

 4. the main thread but on the current queue
```

in the current implementation? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give it a shot. First, without being told by the NSOperationQueue class reference, we could not infer anything about what thread the 'mainQueue' would run on. Reading it we see that in fact that queue runs its operations on the mainThread, the one the UI uses, so you can update the UI in operations posted to that queue. Although it doesn't say it, these operations must be serial, due to them being executed by the runLoop (its possible they can get preempted too, not 100% sure of that).

The purpose for currentQueue is so that running operations can determine the queue they are on, and so they can potentially queue new operations on that queue.

1. a background thread but on the main queue

Not possible - the NSOperation's mainQueue is always associated with the mainThread.

1. a background thread but on the current queue

When you create a NSOperationQueue, and add NSOperations to it, those get run on background threads managed by the queue. Any given operation can query what thread its on, and that thread won't change while it runs. That said, a second operation on that queue may get run on a different thread.

1. the main thread but on the main queue

See 1)

1. the main thread but on the current queue

If you queue an operation to the mainQueue (which we know is always on the mainThread), and you ask for the currentQueue, it will return the mainQueue:

```
[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] == [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, very enlightening indeed! However,I went through the NSOperation & NSOperationQueue class references and there are no guidelines on how to do that, i.e how to create a queue on a background thread and have an operation (e.g. acceleration updates) run on that queue. This is what needs to be done apparently given that running acceleration updates in the background is the safest way to go based on documentation

Comment: If you create your own queue = NSOperationQueue *foo = [NSOperationQueue new];, then queue operations to that, they will get run on a background thread not the mainThread. Read the Apple Concurrency Guide. You may find that blocks are a better choice now adays. I only use NSOperations for concurrency when using NSURLConnections. You can see a simple project on Github I wrote: https://github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy - you'll see how to create a queue, concurrent operation, etc. Its a small project few files.

Comment: Thanks David I'll have a look at your project to see how to exactly implement what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing queues with threads.  Especially since NSOpertionQueue has been rewritten to use GCD, there is little connection between queues and specific threads (except for the special case of the main thread).

Operations/blocks/tasks - whatever you want to call them -  are inserted into a queue, and "worker thread(s)" pull these off and perform them.  You have little control over which exact thread is going to do the work -- except for the main queue.  *Note, this is not exactly right, because it's a simplification, but it's true enough unless you are doing something quite advanced and specific.*

So, none of your 4 scenarios even make sense, because you can't, for example, run something on "a background thread but on the main queue."

Now, your method `startAccelerationUpdates` specifically tells the CMMotionManager to put your handler on the main queue.  Thus, when `startAccelerationUpdates` is called, it gets run in whichever thread it's running, but it schedules the handler to be executed on the main thread.

To somewhat complicate things, you are calling the `startAccelerationUpdates` method by calling `performSelectorInBackground`.  Again, you don't know which thread is going to actually invoke `startAccelerationUpdates`, but it will not be the main thread.

However, in your case, all that thread is doing is calling `startAccelerationUpdates` which is starting motion updates, and telling them to be handled on the main thread (via the main queue).

Now, here's something to dissuade you from using the main queue to handle motion events, directly from the documentation...

> Because the processed events might arrive at a high rate, using the main operation queue is not recommended.

Unfortunately, your statement

> What's even more interesting is that when I call the above method on
>   background thread again, but this time using the current Queue, I get
>   no updates.

does not provide enough information to determine what you tried, how you tried it, or why you think it did not work.  So, I'll make a guess... which may be wrong.

I'll key on your use of `the current Queue`.

I assume you mean that you substitute `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` with `[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]`.

Well, let's see what that does.  Instead of using the main queue, you will be using "some other" queue.  Which one?  Well, let's look at the documentation:

> **currentQueue**
>
> Returns the operation queue that launched the current
>   operation.
>
> `+` (id)currentQueue
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The operation queue that started the operation or nil if the queue could not be determined.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> You can use this method from within a running operation
>   object to get a reference to the operation queue that started it.
>   Calling this method from outside the context of a running operation
>   typically results in nil being returned.

Please note the discussion section.  If you call this when you are not running an operation that was invoked from an `NSOperationQueue`, you will get `nil` which means there will be no queue on which to place your handler.  So, you will get nothing.

You must specify which queue is to be used, if you want to use an `NSOperationQueue` other than the main queue.  So, if that's the route you want to go, just create your own operation queue to handle motion events, and be off!

Good Luck!